# Show that the series $\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac {(n^3+1)^{1/3}-n}{\log n}$ converges

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Show that the series $$\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac {(n^3+1)^{1/3}-n}{\log n}$$ converges.

I showed it using Abel's theorem and limit comparison test. Any other simpler method?

Comment: $$(n^3+1)^{1/3}\leqslant n+\frac1{3n^2}\implies\frac{(n^3+1)^{1/3}-n}{\log n}\leqslant\frac1{3n^2\log n}\implies\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{(n^3+1)^{1/3}-n}{\log n}\ \text{converges}$$

Comment: thank you . abel's + limit comparision was messy.

Comment: @anirudhb How does Abel apply here??

Comment: @MarkViola $\log n$ is increasing function and so inverse of it is decreasing function converging to zero. Now we can show $\sum (n^3+1)^{\frac {1}{3}} - n$ convergent series by limit comparision test with $\frac {1}{n^2}$. now we can apply abel's test

Comment: @anirudhb You meant "[Abel's Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_test)" not "[Abel's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem#Theorem)."  And why not simply realize that $0< \frac{(n^3+1)^{1/3}-n}{\log(n)}\le \frac{(n^3+1)^{1/3}-n}{\log(2)}$ for $n>1$?

Comment: actually @MarkViola i am learning real analysis. This forum is helping in widening my thinking. I am , for the 1st time, seeing so many ways to solve a problem

Comment: @Did it should be "greater than " right instead of less than???? $(n^3+1)^{\frac {1}{3}} = n(1+\frac {1}{n^3})^{\frac {1}{3} }= n(1+ \frac {1}{3} \frac {1}{n^3} )$ (binomial theorem). if we take 2 terms, then it should be "greater than "  right??? pls clarify

Comment: ?? Sorry but what are you talking about? Once again, for every positive integer $n$, $$(n^3+1)^{1/3}\leqslant n+\frac1{3n^2}$$ "Amusingly", the answer you accepted 2 hours before posting your comment to me, allows to  reprove this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write
$$\frac{(n^3+1)^{\frac{1}{3}}-n}{\log n} = \frac{n^3+1-n^3}{\log n((n^3+1)^{2/3}+(n^3+1)^{1/3}n+n^2)} = \frac{1}{\log n((n^3+1)^{2/3}+(n^3+1)^{1/3}n+n^2)}$$
and observe that the denominator goes at $0$ faster than $\frac{1}{n^2}.$

Comment: it should be i think $(n^3 + 1)^{\frac {2}{3}} + (n^3 + 1)^{\frac {1}{3}}n + n^2 $ @Gibbs

Comment: Sure, I forgot the 3's. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Note that

$$(n^3+1)^\frac13=n\left(1+\frac1{n^3}\right)^\frac13\sim n+\frac1{3n^2}$$

thus

$$\frac{(n^3+1)^\frac13-n}{\log n}\sim \frac{1}{3n^2\log n}$$

and thus since $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{3n^2\log n}$ converges also $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(n^3+1)^\frac13-n}{\log n}$ converges by comparison with it.

Comment: (Please avoid posting [duplicate answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2633964/44121))

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I've posted the answer also here because the other OP was declared a duplicate, I delete the other one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\frac{(n^3+1)^\frac13-n}{\ln n}\right)n^2=\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{n^2}{\left(\sqrt[3]{(n^3+1)^2}+n\sqrt[3]{n^3+1}+n^2\right)\ln{n}}=0,$$

then for $n$ large enough we have 
$$\frac{(n^3+1)^\frac13-n}{\ln n}\le \frac{1}{ n^2}$$
the result follows by comparison test. which says that it converges because $$\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}.$$